# <classname> does not name a type

Tags: c++, классы

Здравствуйте!

Есть код:

**room.h**

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "point.h"

using std::vector;

class Room
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;

    int width;
    int height;
    vector<Point> points();

public:
    bool intersects(Room other);
    int area();

    Room(int x_, int y_, int w, int h);
    Room(){;}
    Room(const Room &base){(*this) = base;}


    static Room random(int fWidth, int fHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int minWidth, int minHeight);
    friend bool operator==(Room a, Room b);
    Room operator=(const Room &base);
};

#endif
```

**point.h**

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x_, int y_)
    {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
    }

    Point()
    {
        ;
    }
};

#endif
```

**maze.h**

```
#ifndef MAZE_H
#define MAZE_H

#include <vector>
#include "room.h"

using std::vector;

enum Cell
{
    Empty,
    Room,
    Path
};

class Maze
{
    Cell *field;
    bool *fog;

    int width;
    int height;
    int area;

    void putRooms(int count);

    vector<Room> rooms;

public:
    Maze(int w, int h);
    void print(){}
};

#endif
```

При попытке скомпилировать, компилятор выдает:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
maze.h:27:13: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter lis
t for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'
  vector<Room> rooms;
             ^
maze.h:27:13: note:   expected a type, got 'Room'
maze.h:27:13: error: template argument 2 is invalid
In file included from maze.cpp:1:0:
maze.h:27:13: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter lis
t for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'
  vector<Room> rooms;
             ^
maze.h:27:13: note:   expected a type, got 'Room'
maze.h:27:13: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

При этом, если сразу после `vector<Rooms> rooms;` в maze.h объявить

```
Point x;
vector<Point> y;
```

ошибок больше не станет.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница для компилятора между `Point` и `Room`, и как заставить код компилироваться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Вас член перечисления тоже назван `Room`, это перекрывает класс `Room`.

Переименуйте, используйте namespace или `enum class`.